Configuring cache expiration time in Apache Camel Quarkus
I am working with apache camel in quarkus and I am enabling cache deletion after certain time but I am not able to delete it i.e. I use properties camel.component.caffeine-cache.expire-after-access-time and camel.component.caffeine - cache .expire-after-write-time in the properties, however I am testing it and after setting a time of 60 seconds the query is still done in the cache:
#cache
camel.component.caffeine-cache.expire-after-write-time=60
camel.component.caffeine-cache.expire-after-access-time=60

Test number 1 at 2:00 PM:

Query the cache:
CamelCaffeineActionHasResult =true

Test number 2 at 2:04 PM, in this chaos 240 seconds have already passed since it was cached:

Keep consulting the cache:
CamelCaffeineActionHasResult =true

What could be the cause of this behavior? Shouldn't it be possible to consult the service again outside the cache after the expiration time (60sec)?
This is how I ended up configuring my ResRoute
@ApplicationScoped
public class ResRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "client.findIndividualCustomerByDocId")
    String findIndividualCustomerByDocId;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "client.findOrganizacionCustomerByDocId")
    String findOrganizacionCustomerByDocId;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "path.openapi")
    String pathOpenapi;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "descripcion.servicio")
    String descripcionServicio;
    private ConfigureSsl configureSsl;
    private static final String SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION = "Salida del microservicio BSS FindCustomerByDocId ${exchangeProperty[bodyRs]}";
    private static final String MSG_EXCEPTION = "Descripcion de la Exception: ${exception.message}";

    public ResRoute() {
        configureSsl = new ConfigureSsl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        BeanDate beanDate= new BeanDate();
        getContext().getRegistry().bind("BeanDate",beanDate);
        restConfiguration()
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES")
                .apiContextPath(pathOpenapi)
                .apiProperty("api.title", "FindCustomerByDocId")
                .apiProperty("api.description", descripcionServicio)
                .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0")
                .apiProperty("cors", "true");

        rest("customerInformation/v1.4.0/users/")
                .get("/{user_id}/customers").to("direct:/{user_id}/customers")
                .outType(Customer.class)
                .param().name("FindCustomerByDocIdResponse").type(body).description("parametro de salida").required(true)
                .endParam()
                .to("direct:pipeline");

        from("direct:pipeline")
                .doTry()
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorReq())
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"User ID: ${exchangeProperty[userId]}")
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Correlator ID: ${exchangeProperty[correlatorId]}")
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Tipo de Documento (Num): ${exchangeProperty[documentTypeNum]}")
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Tipo de Cliente: ${exchangeProperty[customerType]}")
                .choice()
                .when(simple("${exchangeProperty[customerType]} == 'NATURAL'"))
                .process(new FindIndividualCustomerByDocIdProcessorReq())
                .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_GET))
                .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY).exchangeProperty("documentNumber")
                .toF("caffeine-cache://%s", "IndividualCache")
                .log("Hay Resultado en Cache de la consulta asociado al siguiente documento: ${exchangeProperty[userId]} ${header.CamelCaffeineActionHasResult}}")
                .log("CamelCaffeineActionSucceeded: ${header.CamelCaffeineActionSucceeded}")
                .choice().when(header(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_HAS_RESULT).isEqualTo(Boolean.FALSE))
                    .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findIndividualCustomerByDocId))
                    .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_PUT))
                    .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY).exchangeProperty("documentNumber")
                    .toF("caffeine-cache://%s", "IndividualCache")
                    .process(new FindIndividualCustomerByDocIdProcessorRes())
                    .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Salida del microservicio FindIndividualCustomerByDocId ${exchangeProperty[findIndividualCustomerByDocIdResponse]}")
                    .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Salida del microservicio BSS FindCustomerByDocId ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerByDocIdResponse]}")
                .otherwise()
                    .log("Cache is working")
                    .process(new FindIndividualCustomerByDocIdProcessorRes())
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Salida del microservicio FindIndividualCustomerByDocId ${exchangeProperty[findIndividualCustomerByDocIdResponse]}")
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Salida del microservicio BSS FindCustomerByDocId ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerByDocIdResponse]}")
                .when(simple("${exchangeProperty[customerType]} == 'JURIDICO'"))
                .process(new FindOrganizationCustomerByDocIdProcessorReq())
                .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findOrganizacionCustomerByDocId))
                .process(new FindOrganizationCustomerByDocIdProcessorRes())
                /*.log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Entrada del microservicio FindOrganizationCustomerByDocId ${exchangeProperty[findOrganizationCustomerByDocIdRequest]}") */
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Salida del microservicio FindOrganizationCustomerByDocId ${exchangeProperty[findOrganizationCustomerByDocIdResponse]}")
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Salida del microservicio BSS FindCustomerByDocId ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerByDocIdResponse]}")
                .endChoice()
                .endDoTry()
                .doCatch(RequiredValueException.class)
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorInvalidFormatException())
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(HttpHostConnectException.class)
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorHttpHostConectionException())
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(NotFoundDataException.class)
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorInformationSubscriber())
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(UnknownHostException.class)
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorHttpHostConectionException())
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(NoHttpResponseException.class)
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorHttpHostConectionException())
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorException())
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION);
    }
}


Configuration options:
camel.component.caffeine-cache.expire-after-write-time
camel.component.caffeine-cache.expire-after-access-time

Only apply when the evictionType option is set to TIME_BASED. The default is SIZE_BASED. Thus write-time & access-time will have no effect.
You can configure the eviction type like this:
camel.component.caffeine-cache.eviction-type = TIME_BASED

See the Camel Caffeine component documentation:
https://camel.apache.org/components/next/caffeine-cache-component.html#_component_option_evictionType
https://camel.apache.org/components/next/caffeine-cache-component.html#_sb_option_camel_component_caffeine-loadcache_eviction-type
